# Scala illegal Inheritance error doesn't make sense

Tags: java, scala, inheritance

I am writing a program in Java and Scala (using interop) and it keeps giving me this compile error wich doesn't make sense....

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   illegal inheritance;   inherits different type instances of trait IEvaluationFunction: core.interfaces.IEvaluationFunction[core.representation.ILinearRepresentation[Double]] and core.interfaces.IEvaluationFunction[core.representation.ILinearRepresentation[Double]]   IConstructors.scala /ScalaMixins - Parjecoliv1/src/aop  line 36 Scala Problem

It says it inherits different types instances, but they are the same. They're both:

> core.interfaces.IEvaluationFunction[core.representation.ILinearRepresentation[Double]]

Can somebody help me solving or understanding this?

The code:

This is where it gives error. The code is in Scala.

```
def createFermentationEvaluation(fermentationProcess:FermProcess,
     interpolationInterval:Int):FermentationEvaluation = {  
  return new FermentationEvaluation(fermentationProcess,interpolationInterval)
    with EvaluationFunctionAspect[ILinearRepresentation[Double]]
}
```

Here are the interface and classes that it uses:

```
public class FermentationEvaluation
  extends EvaluationFunction<ILinearRepresentation<Double>>

trait EvaluationFunctionAspect[T <:IRepresentation]
  extends IEvaluationFunction[T] {...}

public abstract class EvaluationFunction<T extends IRepresentation>
  implements IEvaluationFunction<T>,java.io.Serializable {...}

public interface IRepresentation {...}

public interface ILinearRepresentation<E> extends IRepresentation {...}
```

I didn't include the body of any since it seems to be an inheritance problem.

Comment: Please compile with the flag `-explaintypes`.

Answer (score 3):

One of these types is `java.lang.Double` -- the one defined in Java, where there's no `scala.Double`, and the other is `scala.Double` -- the one defined in Scala.

These are two different types. `scala.Double` is really Java's primitive `double`, and when used as a type parameter it erases to `Object`. It cannot erase to `java.lang.Double` because that breaks when extending types under certain conditions.